# Would airline got charge for late on depart from the gate due to passenger boarding issue? If so, what is the charge like?

Tags: airport-operations, boarding

Airline wants the boarding be completed as quick as possible.  I wonder what is the cost for any delay? On the other hand, I want get a dollar value for any delay and see the justification value for any improvement.  So, I wonder airline would get additional charge for the gate on delay ?
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of cost/charge are you thinking of? A charge/fine from the airport? A charge from a regulatory body? Payments to passengers for delivering them late? More clarity in your question will help you get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Chain of delays

Being late on departure is likely to cause you to be late on arrival, this has the following immediate consequences:

- you may be delayed *even more* on arrival in congested airports (e.g. London) if you miss your scheduled landing timeslot, being forced to circle around for, say, 20-30 minutes wasting fuel and time until you're allowed to land; I have been on a flight like that.
- the main immediate effect is that some transferring passengers may be delayed because of this, which may possibly result in costs to you to reroute or compensate them.
- you likely have scheduled the same airplane for the next flight with a minimal turnaround time; and delayed arrival may easily cause your *next* flight of that same airplane to be delayed (again, I have personally seen delays caused by this)
- you likely have scheduled the same crew for the next flight, and in certain situations that delay may push them over the allowed work/rest schedule, so they are prohibited to fly their next (last in their shift) flight - so you need to rapidly find a new crew for the scheduled flight or cancel it.

For these reasons, a single delay sometimes might cause a chain of other delays or even cancellations, and become quite expensive.

Comment: You may highlight in your answer the part answering the question (would airlines got charged?). All the information you bring to justify avoiding late departure is useful but you may precise how and  if possible how many an airline get charged for all these delays (reroute passengers and crew may be an obvious one, staying at gate is not)

Comment: i wonder airlines are interested on idea to streamline the boarding process to avoid the potential delay.  
As a passenger, would it be nice if we can just walk in without worry about room for the carry on or step over an aisle passenger already on his/her seat.